# Replacing hard value cells with subtotal formula - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Essentially, our system runs off an expenditure listing of cost headings, with a subtotal on each. The issue being we adjust the data, so need to go through and manually turn the hard value subtotals into subtotal formula in each heading; which over hundreds of different headings, with variable numbers of costs, can be tedious and time consuming.

I've built a basic test example whereby for every instance of A (Heading), where the associated B has a value (an element of data from the system for a line of expenditure), the costs (C) will be subtotalled (109,...), replacing the hard copied value.

```
Sub insertsubtotal()
Dim cell As Range
Dim sumrange As Range

Set cell = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A")

Do
    Set cell = cell.End(xlUp)
    Set sumrange = cell.Offset(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 2).Resize(cell.Offset(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1, columnsize:=1)

    If sumrange.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        sumrange.End(xlDown).Offset(2, 0).Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(109," & sumrange.Address & ")"
    Else
        sumrange.Offset(2, 0).Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(109," & sumrange.Address & ")"
    End If
Loop Until cell.Row = 1
End Sub
```

This works whereby the first heading is in A1, and the cost data in column C as below...

[image]

However, where I'm struggling is, I need to amend the process to have the first 5 rows ignored (first heading being on 6), and the cost data and subtotal that needs replacing being in column M.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So your "heading1" will be at "A6", and you current numbers (column "C") will be at Column "M" ? or you just want the result to be in column "M" ?

Comment: Column M would be where the current C data is, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Using `SpecialCells` to divide the `UsedRange` in `Columns("C")` into blocks of contant values, will allow you to easily identify and subtotal your data blocks.

```
Sub insertsubtotal()
    Dim Source As Range, rArea As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        On Error Resume Next
        Set Source = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("C")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Source Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No data found", vbInformation, "Action Cancelled"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        For Each rArea In Source.Areas
            rArea.Offset(rArea.Rows.Count).Cells(2).Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(109," & rArea.Address & ")"
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That's ace thank you; the logic makes sense to me. However this does also subtotal the subtotals, would there be a way to limit it to set of C with more than 1 row?